# Use multiselect dropsown with checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, angular-ui-bootstrap

I got many jQuery plugin, but when I tried in my bootstrap project , it is not working. Could you please suggest me Bootstrap `multiselect` drop-down with checkbox in JSP examples with source code.

I am using below code..it is not working in my template. It is showing simple drop down only.

```
<select id="lstFruits" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Mango</option>
    <option value="2">Apple</option>
    <option value="3">Banana</option>
    <option value="4">Guava</option>
    <option value="5">Orange</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="btnSelected" value="Get Selected" />    

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css"
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#lstFruits').multiselect({
        includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Fixed code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The code sample (edited, latest) above appears to work properly for me. Note that the Bootstrap Multiselect plugin recommends jQuery 2.x or 1.10.x; you are using 1.8.3.

Also, the wrapping `$(function() { ... });` is likely not necessary for what you are trying to accomplish.